# Is there a way to read the file after reading the variable text file through the input stream?

Tags: java, inputstream

I'm reading a variable text every ten seconds through a scheduler.

Currently, i use inputstream-skip() methods to skip already read-content and store only new content.

The terms of the skip were file size.

but, Variable texts are not suitable for use as offsets because of the change in file size.

is there a good way?

I searched for some of the contents. There is a way to read it after it is matched, but this also had many problems

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37442784/java-file-tailer-implementation

Comment: Just read the file till EOF, then sleep for ten seconds, then try another read on the same stream. No offsets or skipping required.